# Unable to save Created attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, admin-panel, custom-attributes

When trying to create and save a new Attribute set. I am presented with a message saying "ATTENTION Sorry, we're unable to complete this request." when trying to save.

Preconditions: 
Magento CE 2.1.3 OR  fresh installation of 2.1.5
- (i tried on both versions)

Steps to reproduce:
Go to Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Sets
Click "Add Attribute Set"
Enter Attribute Set name and select base set ("Default" selected) and click "Save"
Assign attributes (NOTE: this error happens even if no new attributes are assigned)
Click "Save".

I am presented with a notice "ATTENTION Sorry, we're unable to complete this request" (No errors are shown). I am then allowed to a) Close the modal using the "X", or b) Click "OK", which closes the modal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is issue with server configuration. Mod Security was enable and that cause this issue. URl exception is added in configuration in server setting and now issues is fixed.